# Events not firing on iframes

Tags: javascript, events, iframe

I have included an iframe in my page and added a keypress event like this

```
<iframe src = 'mySrchere.com' onkeypress = 'alert(8)'></iframe>
```

But the event is not triggering.?Why is this happening ..So I cannot attach an event with an iframe?
Is it because it is another document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this: `iframe` tag does not support `onkeypress`. You can see the list of tags applicable for `onkeypress` here : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeypress.asp

Comment: w3schools? :(..ok..lemme check